# Should volatile be used for attributes of domain model classes in Java web apps?

Tags: java, wicket, volatile

Here's my thinking:

Even though a HTTP request cycle is essentially handled by a 'single thread', each time a HTTP request is processed for that same session it is likely to be processed by a different thread from the thread pool.

Without the volatile keyword being used on a domain model object, whose lifecycle extends across multiple HTTP requests for the same session, then, according to my understanding, isn't it possible that the attribute could be thread local cached (an optimization by the compiler) in the thread that serviced the first HTTP request? If the second HTTP request is serviced by another thread then that second thread may not see the changes in that attribute that were made by the first thread.

Does this spell "Danger Will Robinson"? Or am I missing a vital plot point about the use (or not) of the volatile keyword?

Comment: `isn't it possible that the attribute could be thread local cached (an optimization by the compiler)` do you have a source for this, the idea that the compiler would choose to handle certain lookups with a thread local? I don't think this is true.

Comment: On this page: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml the author indicates that non volatile variables can be stored 'thread-locally'. It's obviously not the same as using the ThreadLocal class but something happening deep down in the JVM as an optimization which essentially has a 'private copy' of the variable in 'thread scope' memory.

Comment: Looking at that link, I don't believe the author meant thread-locally in the way you are thinking of. It would be insane of the JVM to keep references to objects around (in a thread-local type cache) once the reference is no longer alive. I'm skeptical that this is something that can actually occur.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are forgetting that the threads handling the HTTP request first need to retrieve the instance of the domain model object from the `HttpSession` provided by your application server. The thread handling request 2 in the scenario you describe does not already have an instance of this domain model - it has to retrieve it from the session implementation at the start of handling each and every request.

I think it is completely reasonable to assume that the session-handling implementation in your application server is handling session data in such a way that memory model visibility issues are avoided. Apache Tomcat's default (non-clustered) [`HttpSession` implementation, for example, stores the session attributes in a ConcurrentHashMap](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_0/java/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.java).

Adding `volatile` seems completely unnecessary to me. I have never seen this done for domain model objects handled by HTTP requests in a Servlet environment in any project I have worked in.

This would be a different story if thread-1 and thread-2 had references to the same object instance *simulatenously* while processing two different requests, and you were concerned about changes in one thread being visible to the other *as each* are processing the request, but this does not sound like what you are asking about.

Comment: I was thinking about the case where we're using OpenSessionInView or OpenPersistenceManagerInView and so our session object has references to (detached) domain objects. If, during one HTTP request, one thread made a change to an object's attribute then in a later HTTP request for the same session, a different thread accessed that value it might not see the change made by the other thread if not marked as volatile. Or are you saying this can't happen because the change made by thread 1 will always be flushed to real memory (even without marking the attribute as volatile)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are sharing an object between different threads, you may have race conditions.  Without a happens before relationship, writes made by one thread may not be seen by a read in another thread.

Doing a volatile write in one thread and doing a volatile read of the same field in another thread establishes a happens before relationship between the two threads, and ensures visibility of the write.

This is a complicated problem, simply using a volatile keyword is probably not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of it is correct. Given your description I would say it should be used. If its something more than a primitive type I would rather synchronize.

Good information on volatile:
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_when.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mutable object in session, that is trouble. But usually the solution is not to guard individual fields; rather the entire object should be swapped.

Say you have the user object in the session. Most requests simply retrieve it, read it and display it.

There is a request that can modify user information. It would be a really bad idea to retrieve the user object, modify **it**. It's better to create complete new user object, and insert it into session.

In that case, fields in User don't need any protection; thread safety is guaranteed by session setAttribute() - getAttribute()

Comment: The admin side of web apps we write change object attributes in forms etc., all the time. To have to create a new instance and replace the original in the object graph every time it changed would be slightly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you have concurrency issues, just adding 'volatile' probably won't help you.

As for keeping the object as an attribute of Session, I'd recommend you to keep just the object's ID, and use it to retrieve a 'live' instance when you need it (if you use Hibernate, successive retrieves will return the same object, so this shouldn't cause performance problems). Encapsulate all modification logic to this specific object into a single façade, and do the control concurrency there, using dababase locking.

Or, if you really, really, really want to use memory-based locking, and are really sure that you'll never have two instances of the application running in a cluster, make sure that your façade logic is synchronized at the right level. If your synchronization is too fine grained (low-level operations, *such as volatile variables*), it probably won't be enough to make your code thread-safe. For example, `java.util.Hashtable` is fully synchronized, but it doesn't mean anything if you have logic like this:

```
01    if (!hashtable.containsKey(key)) {
02        hashtable.put(key, calculate(key));
03    }
```

If two threads, say, `t1` and `t2`, hit this block at the same time, `t1` may execute line `01`, then `t2` may also execute `01`, and then `02`, and `t1` then will execute `02`, overwriting what `t2` had done. The operations `containsKey()` and `put()` are atomic individually, but what should be atomic is the whole block.

Sometimes recalculating a value doesn't matter, but sometimes it does, and it *will* break.

When it comes to concurrency, there's no magic. I mean, <strike>seam</strike> some crappy frameworks try to sell you the idea that they solve this problem for you. They don't. Even if it works 99% of the time, it will break spectacularly when you go to production and start to get heavy traffic. Or (much, much) worse, it will silently generate wrong results.

Concurrency is one of the most complex problems in programming. And the only way to handle it is to avoid it. All this functional programming trend is not about dealing with concurrency, is about avoiding it altogether.

Comment: We effectively are doing that by using detach/attach of JDO (similar to Hibernate/JPA's attach/detach concept). I understand concurrency issues but this is slightly different - no chance of two different threads accessing the same thing at the same time (our servlet filter/model exposer/dependency injector prevents concurrent processing of more than one HTTP request for the same session) but potentially two different threads at different times modifying/reading attributes of a class. Perhaps using detach/attach means we don't have a problem.

Comment: Oh, I get it.. Looking behind, I've never worried about this, but this really can be a problem, in theory. Well, if attach/detach is the same as in Hibernate, then it won't solve the problem, since it doesn't concern the entity, but the session. You'd have to either declare the attributes as volatile, or always wrap logic around these attributes with synchronized blocks/methods (if you do this at the request level, maybe it is sufficient). Anyway, I (contradicting what I've said before :)) wouldn't worry too much about it, unless something breaks, since the chance of this happening is very low

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that volatile was not needed in the end. The problem that "appeared" to be fixed with volatile was actually a very subtle timing sensitive bug that was fixed in a much more elegant and proper way ;)

So sbrigdes was correct when he said "simply using a volatile keyword is probably not a good solution."